# obtener ultimo estatus

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo dos tablas.
Una de pedidos web, con toda la información asociada a las ventas web y otra donde se almacenan todos los status y fechas de los pedidos web con envíos a domicilio.

la primera tabla (de pedidos) es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la segunda tabla va así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda, lo que no he podido lograr es traer el status_id que se obtuvo de último y agregarlo a una consulta relacionando ambas tablas por el numero de pedido, deseo obtener todos los pedidos que no han sido entregados, esto es, pedidos con estatus != 10. Lo obtengo bien, pero al consultar por pedidos que han sido devueltos me da por ejemplo 10 pedidos devueltos, pero al volver al consultar toda la traza, hay pedidos que en algun momento fueron devueltos pero que al final de todo el proceso pudieron ser entregados, por ende se solapan, es decir, aparecen en la consulta con estatus devueltos y vuelven a aparecer en la consulta de entregados.
¿cómo filtro por el último estatus o fecha de estatus mayor, el último estatusde la traza de un pedido?
Lo intenté así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pedido_web_largo), MAX(created_at), status_id, name  
FROM TRACKING 
WHERE pedido_web_largo IN (SELECT * FROM #TMP_PEDIDOS_WEB ) 
    group by pedido_web_largo, status_id, name, created_at
```

y trae toda la traza

Comment: Hola Virginia! Tienes forma de modificar tus tablas? Lo comento porque, desde mi punto de vista, en la segunda tabla te falta algo que indique la forma en que deberían estar ordenados los diferentes estatus de tu pedido. Pensé usar estatus_id, pero "entregado" tiene id=10, cuando "listo para despacho"=26, eso me hace pensar que el estatus_id lo seleccionaron de forma aleatoria, por lo que no sirve para este fin. Yo te recomendaría agregar un campo fecha, o ya de perdido algo como un ID. Suerte!

Comment: Ahora que veo bien, parece que a la segunda tabla le ocultaste la primer columna, ¿qué hay ahí? Tal vez se podría usar...

Comment: El `pedido_web_largo` es el mismo que el `tracking_number`? O como relacionas ambas tablas?

Comment: @LuisCazares no es igual.  La relación entre ambas tablas es el pedido_web_largo

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras es solo el id de la tabla

Comment: Necesitas poner las definiciones correctas de las tablas, no imágenes cortadas que no tienen todas las columnas relevantes.

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomendaría que en la tabla de pedidos agregues el campo status_id en donde se almacenará el **último estado del pedido**. Así podrás saber cual es el estado del pedido.
Suerte!.